# How to position divs next to each other and under each other?

Tags: css, html, positioning

This is probably is a stupid question and it's really easy to solve, but I am having trouble doing so. My question is, how do I position the two last sections (shown in the picture) below the first ones?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/829/63128947.jpg/

This is my code:

```
#main_div{
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
border: 1px solid black;
max-width: 1000px;
}

#main_section{
width: 600px;
height: 450px;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
}

#sub_section1{
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
}

#sub_section2{
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
}

#sub_section3{
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
}

#sub_section4{
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Use `float: left` on all elements inside of `#main_div` and constrain `#main_div` to not have enough space for those two, then they will wrap down to the next line. Another option would be to use the `nth-child` pseudo-selector, instead of selecting by ID.

Comment: Read this: http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-HTML5-Programming-JavaScript/dp/1449390544 It's a LOT quicker and easier to get a good foundation in HTML, rather than keep banging your head against walls and learning that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvvHJ/) that demonstrates one way to do it. I simply added another `div` element (I called it a "sidebar"), and put the smaller `div`s inside of it. Each element is floated, and the width of the sidebar container is wide enough to contain these elements. You may need to resize the viewport in the fiddle to get things to flow as you have them in your screenshot.

Since your smaller `div` elements are all styled the same, I opted to use a class instead of multiple ID's. This way you aren't duplicating rules unnecessarily in your CSS.

Also note that this could also probably be achieved with absolute positioning, if you're into that kind of thing. There are usually multiple ways of doing things in CSS.

Answer (score -1):

I just added another layer of conatining divs and called them section_top/bottom. Since divs are block elements, it should push the other two down. I also cleaned up the styles just a little :-).

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CSilivestru/5Fd9P/)

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #main_div{
                display: -webkit-box;
                -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
                border: 1px solid black;
                max-width: 1000px;
                padding: 5px;
                margin: 10px;
            }

            #main_section{
                width: 600px;
                height: 450px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            .subsection {
                width: 100px;
                height: 200px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 5px;
                margin: 10px;
                -webkit-box-flex: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main_div">
            <div id="main_section">

            </div>
            <div id="section_top">
                <div id="sub_section1" class="subsection">

                </div>
                <div id="sub_section2" class="subsection">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="section_bottom">
                <div id="sub_section3" class="subsection">

                </div>
                <div id="sub_section4" class="subsection">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```